# Process multiple tables in a form and post to next page - without MySQL

Tags: php, post, html-table, form-submit

Why is only the bottom table in the form being processed to the next page? If they enter quantities from multiple styles(multiple tables), I want the info rendered in separate tables(rows) on the next page. A sample of what I am trying to do is here:       http://taketwodesigns.com/monkeypod/order/BACKUPS/items/ladies/index.php

If I enter Qty's in the top 2 tables, no data is rendered on next page.
If I enter Qty's in bottom table info renders fine!
Do I need to give names to each submit button? Maybe add an if(isset()?

I'm trying to create an order form for apparel without needing the full-blown shopping cart! No payment is needed.(Would ultimately like to be able to email a PDF of rendered page) 
Thanks!

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Pacific/Honolulu');
$date = date("l, F jS Y g:i:s A");

$itemName = $_POST['submitIt'];
$itemStyle = $_POST['itemStyle'];
$mistake = '<p class="mistakes">If you have entered the wrong quantities,     simply go<a href="javascript:history.back();"> BACK</a> and re-enter them.    </p>';

$xs  = $_POST['xs'];
$sm  = $_POST['sm'];
$md  = $_POST['md'];
$lg  = $_POST['lg'];
$xl  = $_POST['xl'];
$xxl = $_POST['xxl'];

if ($_POST['xs'] ||
    $_POST['sm'] ||
    $_POST['md'] ||
    $_POST['lg'] ||
    $_POST['xl'] ||
    $_POST['xxl'] &&
    $_POST['submitIt'] &&        
    $_POST['itemStyle']) {

for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['submitIt']); $i++) {

    $xs = ltrim($_POST['xs'][$i], '0');
    $sm = ltrim($_POST['sm'][$i], '0');
    $md = ltrim($_POST['md'][$i], '0');
    $lg = ltrim($_POST['lg'][$i], '0');
    $xl = ltrim($_POST['xl'][$i], '0');
    $xxl = ltrim($_POST['xxl'][$i], '0');

    include '../../BACKUPS/templates/process_table_template.php';                    
    }
}else {
    echo '<h2>Oppsiedasies! It looks like you didn\'t order anything!    <br>Back to <a href="..">shop home</a></h2>';
}
?>
```

Styles and sizes of garments are in multiple tables in a single form element. Like below. (just assume there are multiple styles, some without XS, XL or XXL sizes)

```
<form action="/monkeypod/order/BACKUPS/processors/process_xs-xxl.php" class="margins" name="ladies" method="post">
<span class="item_kind">↓ Ladies Items ↓</span>

<!---------- 1st STYLE BELOW ----------->
<div class="itemz">

<div class="item_image_container">
<span class="item_name">Item ~ MLTA107-101TEV</span>
<a href="/monkeypod/order/BACKUPS/images/styles/large/mlta107_101tev_big.jpg" target="_blank">
<img class="item_image" src="/monkeypod/order/BACKUPS/images/styles/thumbs/mlta107_101tev_thumb.png" /></a>
<span class="click_full_image">Click image for full size</span>
</div><!-- ITEM_IMAGE_CONTAINER div CLOSE -->

<table id="styles" border="1" cellspacing="1">
<tr class="gridaddrows">
<td colspan=8 class="radius">
<div class="formtext">Enter quantities and click the revolving can to submit</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr class="gridrows">
<td class="gridtitle">Size ►</td>
<td class="gridtitle">XS</td>
<td class="gridtitle">SM</td>
<td class="gridtitle">MD</td>
<td class="gridtitle">LG</td>
<td class="gridtitle"></td>
<td class="gridtitle"></td>
</tr>

<td class="add_to_cart_btn">
<input type="image" src="/monkeypod/order/BACKUPS/images/clicktoadd83pxfast.gif" alt="Add to Cart"></td>
<input type="hidden" name="itemName" value="MLTA107-101TEV">

<td><span class="price">$11.25</span><br>
<input type="number" name="xs" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" autocomplete="off"></td>

<td><span class="price">$11.25</span><br>
<input type="number" name="sm" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" autocomplete="off"></td>

<td><span class="price">$11.25</span><br>
<input type="number" name="md" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" autocomplete="off"></td>

<td><span class="price">$11.25</span><br>
<input type="number" name="lg" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288"  autocomplete="off"></td>

<td><!-- span class="price">$11.25</span><br -->
<input type="number" name="xl" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" style="visibility: hidden;" autocomplete="off"></td>

<td><!-- span class="price">$11.25</span><br -->
<input type="number" name="xxl" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" style="visibility: hidden;" autocomplete="off"></td>

</table>
</div><!-- ITEMZ div CLOSE -->

<!------ 2nd STYLE BELOW ---------------->
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect that the 2nd style looks exactly the same as the first. If you want to precess multiple items with exact same structure, you should use arrays. You can do this by adding brackets to your inputs names:

```
<form action="/monkeypod/order/BACKUPS/processors/process_xs-xxl.php" class="margins" name="ladies" method="post">
<span class="item_kind">↓ Ladies Items ↓</span>

<!---------- 1st STYLE BELOW ----------->
<div class="itemz">

<div class="item_image_container">
<span class="item_name">Item ~ MLTA107-101TEV</span>
<a href="/monkeypod/order/BACKUPS/images/styles/large/mlta107_101tev_big.jpg" target="_blank">
<img class="item_image" src="/monkeypod/order/BACKUPS/images/styles/thumbs/mlta107_101tev_thumb.png" /></a>
<span class="click_full_image">Click image for full size</span>
</div><!-- ITEM_IMAGE_CONTAINER div CLOSE -->

<table id="styles" border="1" cellspacing="1">
<tr class="gridaddrows">
<td colspan=8 class="radius">
<div class="formtext">Enter quantities and click the revolving can to submit</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr class="gridrows">
<td class="gridtitle">Size ►</td>
<td class="gridtitle">XS</td>
<td class="gridtitle">SM</td>
<td class="gridtitle">MD</td>
<td class="gridtitle">LG</td>
<td class="gridtitle"></td>
<td class="gridtitle"></td>
</tr>

<td class="add_to_cart_btn">
<input type="image" src="/monkeypod/order/BACKUPS/images/clicktoadd83pxfast.gif" alt="Add to Cart"></td>
<input type="hidden" name="itemName[]" value="MLTA107-101TEV">

<td><span class="price">$11.25</span><br>
<input type="number" name="xs[]" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" autocomplete="off"></td>

<td><span class="price">$11.25</span><br>
<input type="number" name="sm[]" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" autocomplete="off"></td>

<td><span class="price">$11.25</span><br>
<input type="number" name="md[]" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" autocomplete="off"></td>

<td><span class="price">$11.25</span><br>
<input type="number" name="lg[]" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288"  autocomplete="off"></td>

<td><!-- span class="price">$11.25</span><br -->
<input type="number" name="xl[]" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" style="visibility: hidden;" autocomplete="off"></td>

<td><!-- span class="price">$11.25</span><br -->
<input type="number" name="xxl[]" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" style="visibility: hidden;" autocomplete="off"></td>

</table>
</div><!-- ITEMZ div CLOSE -->

<!------ 2nd STYLE BELOW ---------------->
```

Your $_POST variables will look like this if you have 2 styles (dummy example):

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST['xs']);
    /*
        array(2) => (
            [0](string) => '1',
            [1](string) => '1'
        )
    */
?>
```

In php file which processes form input, loop through $_POST array. 
That could look like something like this (I just changed relevant parts of your code to be able to process arrays, it just shows how it could be done, not tested):

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Pacific/Honolulu');
    {...}
    if (((is_array($_POST['xs']) && !empty($_POST['xs'])) ||
        (is_array($_POST['sm']) && !empty($_POST['sm'])) ||
        (is_array($_POST['md']) && !empty($_POST['md'])) ||
        (is_array($_POST['lg']) && !empty($_POST['lg'])) ||
        (is_array($_POST['xl']) && !empty($_POST['xl'])) ||
        (is_array($_POST['xxl']) && !empty($_POST['xxl']))) &&
        (is_array($_POST['itemName']) && !empty($_POST['itemName']))
    ) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['itemName']); $i++) {
            $xs = ltrim($_POST['xs'][$i], '0');
            {...}
        }
    } else {
        echo '<h2>Oppsiedasies! It looks like you didn\'t order anything!             <br>Back to <a href="..">shop home</a></h2>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: So do I use the code that you have inside the "commented-out" area in place of the code in my "if" statement?

Comment: No the commented area shows the output of `var_dump($_POST['xs'])`.

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't gotten that far with arrays yet... mind a little more detailed help? Will I have a stack of "var_dump($_POST['xs'])" according to how many sizes I have. Then, the number "2" in the "array(2)"  designates how many styles I have on the page?

Comment: I updated my answer. It's just an untested example how it could be done. See it as an example to lead you on the right track... The `if statement` is updated to check `$_POST` vars if they are of type `array` and if they're not empty. If condition is met, the `for loop` loops through all the rows the user filled.

Comment: Thanks for that! We're getting closer! I updated my original PHP code above... Isn't the "POST" an array already? I removed bits and pieces of you code to try it with less code and it kinda works now. The different item names are not posting on the next page to each item title area at the top of the tables. The same item number is showing up in the item title area. And it's processing all tables, even when they're not filled in. http://taketwodesigns.com/monkeypod/order/BACKUPS/items/ladies/index.php

Comment: Yes the PHP `$_POST` variable is always an array, but mostly an array of strings. Now its a multilevel array of strings (array of arrays). In the `for` loop you can check each `$size` if `$_POST[$size][$i]` is empty, and if all are empty the table is not filled...